# How can I avoid rpivotTable overlapping rest of HTML report?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-markdown, rpivottable

I am trying to include an rpivotTable in my HTML report but it keeps overlapping the graph I have below.

This is an example code so that you can see that when you render Rmd to HTML it will overlap whatever is below.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mt <- mtcars

rpivotTable::rpivotTable(mtcars, rows = mpg, columns = c(cyl, hp))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I have tried using the height and width arguments with no success.

As the pivot table is interactive and can change in size, I would like the graph below to automatically make space to fit the pivot table.

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: You problem is not reproducible with you've given. Can you provide runnable code to look at exact problem?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by runnable? Here is the whole Rmd file: ---
title: "try"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
mt<-mtcars

rpivotTable::rpivotTable(mtcars, rows = "mpg", cols = c("cyl", "hp"))

ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg, cyl))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Runnable mean one can copy paste and start working to help you. With your clarification I was able to provide an answer.

Comment: You could add styling to make it a resizeable table. Using style tags, you would probably want to use something like `<style>.rpivotTable{resize:both;overflow:auto;</style>`. You can put that anywhere outside of an R chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Include both objects in different divs in markdown. You can format height there:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

<div style="height: 1500px;" markdown="1">
```{r a, echo=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
mt<-mtcars  

rpivotTable::rpivotTable(mtcars, rows = "mpg", cols = c("cyl", "hp"))  

```


</div>
<div style="height: 100%;" markdown="2">
```{r b, echo=FALSE}



ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg, cyl))+   geom_bar(stat="identity")

```
</div>
````

Comment: Thanks. If I also include <div style="overflow: scroll;" markdown="1"> it lets me fit the table and scroll the overflow.